# Scala/Spark can't match function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
df = df.withColumn("DATATmp", to_date($"DATA", "yyyyMMdd"))
```

And getting this error:

```
<console>:34: error: too many arguments for method to_date: (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

How could I specify the exactly function to import? Has another way to avoid this error?

EDIT: Spark version 2.1

Comment: Thats strange. Can you share sample input data so that we can try to. That error should not have occured at all

Comment: As Andrey specified only works for 2.2, my spark is 2.1, as a "recent" version I did not expect to have version issues and thought was a spark issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As can be seen [in the detailed scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), the `to_date` function with two parameters has been added in 2.2.0, whereas the one-argument version existed since 1.5.

If you are working with an older Spark version, either upgrade, or don't use this function.